# Load current computation of complicated resistance network

Tags: current, resistors, load

I'm reading Electronic Principles 6th edition by Malvino. Problem 1.28 describes a network of resistors that I would like to know how to solve mathematically instead of experimentally (as described in the book).
 I got the response below from another site. The author used a slightly different schematic which I accept, although his answer looks reasonable, it was not confirmed by my simulation.
 Using his schematic is he right? How can the math be done if the resistors are not all the same at 1 ohm?

[image: ResistorCube]

Comment: Try a Y-Δ transform or two, see where that takes you.

Comment: Without the symmetry entailed by setting all of the cube resistors to be equal (or at least the 3 sets which are used in the computation) the problem gets very messy indeed. There are 6 voltage loops which obey KVL, and 8 corners/nodes which obey KCL, and you would need to simultaneously solve the 14 equations which are produced. This would be tedious, to say the least, although this is exactly the sort of thing computers are good at. And speaking of such, my SPICE simulation comes out exactly in agreement with this answer, so I suspect your simulation was done wrong - you should recheck it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the 'cube body diagonal resistance: all same value resistors" is trivial to solve.
The trick is to connect up 'symmetrical' points as they all have at the same voltage. The system then collapses into standard parallel and series resistors.

If the resistors are different you have to make, as @WhatRoughBeast says, a system of simultaneous equations. There are computer programs to solve those but YOU still have to write the equations. My guess is you need 7 equations: One for each side of the cube and a seventh for power..ground loop.

By the way: you can also solve this also if you have impedances instead of resistors. It just gets a bit more challenging.

I wrote program to solve up to 20x20 complex equations but have not used it yet